# Can any apps print from the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, software-recommendation, printing

Can any apps print from the iPhone? Preferably via WiFi...and to an Epson PX710 all-in-one in my case.

Comment: (to an Epson PX710 all-in-one in my case)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Apple’s AirPrint Wireless Printing for iPad, iPhone & iPod touch Coming
>   to Users in November**
>
> CUPERTINO, California—September 15,
>   2010—Apple® today announced that it is
>   releasing a beta version of its
>   AirPrint wireless printing for iPad™,
>   iPhone® and iPod touch® to members of
>   Apple’s iOS developer program today,
>   and that AirPrint will be included in
>   the free iOS 4.2 software update in
>   November. AirPrint automatically finds
>   printers on local networks and can
>   print text, photos and graphics to
>   them wirelessly over Wi-Fi without the
>   need to install drivers or download
>   software. HP’s existing and upcoming
>   ePrint enabled printers will be the
>   first to support printing direct from
>   iOS devices.

Via [Apple.com](http://www.apple.com/pr/library/2010/09/15airprint.html).

Answer (score 5):

If you want to print pictures and photos, you can use [Epson iPrint](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/epson-iprint/id326876192?mt=8) (there are similar apps from other printer manufacturers, e.g. [Canon iEPP](http://www.usa.canon.com/cusa/consumer/standard_display/iepp_home), [HP iPrint Photo 2.0](http://itunes.apple.com/app/hp-iprint-photo-2-0/id299531647?mt=8), [Kodak Pic Flick](http://www.kodak.com/eknec/PageQuerier.jhtml?pq-path=15727&CID=go&idhbx=picflick) or [Lexmark LexPrint](http://support.lexmark.com/index?locale=en&userlocale=EN_US&productCode=LEXPRINT&page=recommendedDownloads&segment=DOWNLOAD)). For printing PDFs or other documents, the already mentioned "print n share", "Print Bureau" (both from [eurosmartz](http://www.eurosmartz.com/)) or [Air Sharing Pro](http://avatron.com/apps/air-sharing-pro/) from Avatron could be useful.

Answer (score 2):

[Print n Share](http://appshopper.com/productivity/print-share-printing-for-emails-files-contacts-web-pages-photos-and-more) perhaps.

There also are a bunch of other apps for this in the app store.